# CCTMXTiledMap: OpenGL error : 0x0502 in -[CCSprite draw]

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I used CCTMXTiledMap and added some coins sprite to the base map. getting these error.

> 2013-07-18 23:43:16.794 [5089:13c3] cocos2d: CCSpriteBatchNode:
>   resizing TextureAtlas capacity from [285] to [381]. OpenGL error
>   0x0502 in -[CCSprite draw] 530

Code:

```
CCTMXTiledMap *tileMap = [[CCTMXTiledMap alloc] initWithTMXFile:tilemapFile];
```

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: Can you please show you tilemap code here.? I think its related to the sprites you have used.

Comment: I just created new sprite with spriteFrame from sheet and added that to tileMap...

Comment: how big is your tilemap and how many layers? CCTMXTiledMap is limited to a total of 65536 tiles (counting all set tiles on all layers).

Comment: 19 tiles in row, 32 in column, background and meta layer, 32x19x2=1216, so inside limit. still getting opengl error